# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib', even after pip installing and pipenv installing

Tags: python, pipenv, passlib

So I know, it seems this question has been asked before, but I do believe I have a unique situation.

I'm developing a Flask app (specifics below). I've created a virtual environment with pipenv.
But no matter what I try, I keep getting this error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'**

I've tried:

- pip install passlib
- pip3.9 install passlib
- pipenv install passlib
- uninstalling passlib, then pipenv install passlib again

And I'm running out of ideas....

Here is some context:

---

Python version: 3.9.9
pip version: 20.1.1
Flask version: 1.1.2
Werkzeug version: 1.0.1

OS : Windows 10
Editor: VS Code

Part of the code where I get the error message:

```html
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to a friend I found a workaround.
This workaround might point in the direction of a permanent solution...

So here's the workaround I used:

- I figured out where pipenv stores the files for the passlib module
- I copied all the folders related to passlib into my main project folder

PRESTO !  Error message gone...